# When testing async functions with Mocha/Chai, a failure to match an expectation always results in a timeout

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocha.js, chai

For example, I have something basic like this:

```
it.only('tests something', (done) => {
  const result = store.dispatch(fetchSomething());
  result.then((data) => {
    const shouldBe = 'hello';
    const current = store.something;
    expect(current).to.equal(shouldBe);
    done();
  }
});
```

When `current` does not match `shouldBe`, instead of a message saying that they don't match, I get the generic timeout message:

> Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being
>   called in this test.

It's as if the expectation is pausing the script or something. How do I fix this? This is making debugging nearly impossible.

Comment: Usually with async code you would pass done() into your callback and execute your expectation there like:

`store.getState().get('something', function (err, data){ expect...;done() }})`

Comment: Unless, you're returning a promise, line 5 isn't going to work with async code.

Comment: Sorry maybe that was a bad example, but the async part is within `result.then((data) => {`. The getState() part is not async.

Comment: Line 5 isn't async. It's a redux store using immutableJS. Sorry for the confusion, I'll edit the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expectation is not *pausing* the script, it is throwing an exception before you hit the `done` callback, but since it is no longer inside of the test method's context it won't get picked up by the test suite either, so you are never completing the test. Then your test just spins until the timeout is reached.

You need to capture the exception at some point, either in the callback or in the `Promise`'s error handler.

```
it.only('tests something', (done) => {
  const result = store.dispatch(fetchSomething());
  result.then((data) => {
    const shouldBe = 'hello';
    const current = store.getState().get('something');
    try {
      expect(current).to.equal(shouldBe);
      done();
    } catch (e) {
      done(e);
    } 
  });
});
```

**OR**

```
it.only('tests something', (done) => {
  const result = store.dispatch(fetchSomething());
  result.then((data) => {
    const shouldBe = 'hello';
    const current = store.getState().get('something');
    expect(current).to.equal(shouldBe);

  })
  .catch(done);
});
```

**Edit**

If you are not opposed to bringing in another library, there is a fairly nice library call [chai-as-promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/). That gives you some nice utilities for this kind of testing.

Comment: THANK YOU! So Chai's `expect` actually throws an exception when there's no match... that makes perfect sense now that I think about it.

Comment: Pretty much, though it is technically the assertion function, `equal` in this case that usually throws if the expectation is not met.

Comment: Aye that's what I meant. Thanks.