# How to end async mocha test inside a then()

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I need to perform two consecutive POSTs in my test, and so I have the second nested in a callback inside of a then(). When I try running my test, I get this error: `Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

Here is my code:

```
it('it should not create a user with a username already in the database', (done) => {
        let user = {
            "username": "myusername",
            "password": "password"
        };
        chai.request(server)
            .post('/user')
            .send(user)
            .then((response) => {
                chai.request(server)
                .post('/user')
                .send(user)
                .then((res) => {
                    res.should.have.status(406);
                    done();
                }); 
            });
 });
```

I've tried increased my timeout limit, and that didn't work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You should always have a `.catch`.

```
.then(response => ...)
.catch(e => assert.equal(e.message, "Expecting data"))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mocha supports promises](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises), and it's best to use that support if you're testing promise-based code:

```
it('it should not create a user with a username already in the database', () => {
  let user = {
    "username": "myusername",
    "password": "password"
  };
  return chai.request(server)
    .post('/user')
    .send(user)
    .then((response) => {
      return chai.request(server)
        .post('/user')
        .send(user)
        .then(() => {
          // We're _expecting_ a promise rejection, so throw if it resolves:
          throw Error('should not be reached');
        }, res => {
          res.should.have.status(406);
        }); 
    });
});
```

Otherwise, the following may happen: the assertion (`res.should.have.status(406)`) may fail, which throws an error, which causes `done` never to get called, causing a timeout.

You can catch that assertion error with `.catch` and call `done` with the error, but you have to do that for all your tests, which is a bit tedious. It's also error-prone, because if, for some reason, a new error gets thrown inside the `.catch`, you end up with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is good approach too, I think, but it's still giving me the Not Acceptable exception on my `then`s because they don't have failure callbacks. Seems like either way, I'll have to go through the tedium of exception-catching.

Comment: @Kaitlyn okay I see the issue now: `chai-http` rejects the request promise when it gets an error status code (like 406), so the assertion is never checked. I'll update my code.

Comment: This works for me if I add a failure callback to the outer then as well

Comment: @Kaitlyn ah, so the top-level `chai.request()` may also cause a 406? In that case, yes, you need to also add a failure callback for that one. Although if the top-level request may also cause a 406, I don't see the point of nesting two of them. Unless you don't reset the backend for each test.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. Found the answer on this post: [When testing async functions with Mocha/Chai, a failure to match an expectation always results in a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748343/when-testing-async-functions-with-mocha-chai-a-failure-to-match-an-expectation?rq=1)

The reason it was never hitting my `done` calls was that it was hitting an uncaught exception and never returning. I wasn't providing a failure callback inside of my `then`s, and the Not Acceptable exception was being thrown.

Here is my fixed code:

```
it('it should not create a user with a username already in the database', (done) => {
        let user = {
            "username": "anh",
            "password": "pass"
        };
        chai.request(server)
            .post('/user')
            .send(user)
            .then((response) => {
                chai.request(server)
                .post('/user')
                .send(user)
                .then(() => {
                    throw Error('Something went wrong');
                },
                (res) => {
                    res.should.have.status(406);
                    done();
                });
            },
            (res) => {
                throw Error('Something went wrong');
            });
    });
```

Comment: This will also allow error responses that don't have a 406 status code to pass the test.

Comment: Throwing those errors will result in _"unhandled promise rejection"_ errors in case they are hit.